# Push notiifcation not working when updated macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pem, macos-sierra

Push notification not working when we updated macOS Sierra, follow below process to create **.pem** file.

-open key chain export certificates to desktop give name as Dev.p12 .

-In terminal use below command to create .pem file :-

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in Dev.p12 -out ConsumerDev.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

-.pem file successfully created install same file on server however notification not received on device .

When we had created .pem file in **ElCapitan** OS push notification working fine but problem in sierra OS update.is any other command in Sierra to create .pem file of or need to install some other certificates.Please give us solution how to fix it.